# Replace Text On Pygame Window

Tags: python, text, pygame

I am making a score system on my python file. I tried using this:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
text = font.render('Score: '+str(score), True, black)
gameDisplay.blit(text, [0,0])
```

For some reason, the new score goes on top of the old score, and you can't read it. It makes a huge blob of numbers. Is there a way of replacing the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your game loop, you have to clear what was previously drawn by filling the screen then painting:

```
gameDisplay.fill(your_color_tuple)

# afterwards add your drawing code
```